# Why does this code make my screen go blank in admin when I put it in functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When publishing content or changing any settings in the admin, the screen goes blank, I found that it's due to this code in my `functions.php` file. Is there something wrong with it?

```
<?php
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') ) {
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=> 'Footer',
    'id' => 'footer',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '<div class="title">',
    'after_title' => '</div>'
));
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=> 'Right-Sidebar',
    'id' => 'rightsidebar',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="white-bar">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<div class="title">',
    'after_title' => '</div>'
));
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=> 'Ads',
    'id' => 'ads',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '<div class="title">',
    'after_title' => '</div>'
));
}
?>
```

Fairly new to this, so details would be excellent!

Comment: There is no `register_sidebar` function.

Comment: Activate error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`

Comment: Turn on debugging in your wp-config. `define(WP_DEBUG, true);` This will let you know exactly where the issue stems.

Comment: @Pekka, WordPress sets this in the core. You have to use `WP_DEBUG`.

Comment: @develroot there is a function register_sidebar in WordPress: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar

Comment: @Paul Bain yes, i know. at least it's not defined in current context.

Comment: @develroot if that were the case though, it wouldn't cause the page to blank via a fatal error, it just wouldn't execute the following code

Comment: @Paul Bain does the author mention a fatal error? What he says is `the screen goes blank`.

Comment: @develroot execution wouldn't stop unless it's a fatal error

Comment: +1 @jere - PHP would produce output if it wasn't fatal.

Comment: Ok, so what's the best step from here? Not sure where or how to include the code you guys posted, and just so everyone knows, although the screen goes blank it seems that wordpress still executes whichever button I press for changes/posting.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I added that and got this: 'Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/brightbo/public_html/sociabulls/wp-content/themes/sociabulls/functions.php:7) in /home1/brightbo/public_html/sociabulls/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 866'

Comment: Seems like the page can't redirect because of output. Look at the lines in the files it references and ensure it's not outputting anything.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Un-needed spacing in the functions.php file was causing this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not be the answer, but I have run into this problem before, and on several occasions it was some extra whitespace at the top or bottom of the functions.php file.

Maybe check that if nothing else works.

It could be a number of things, but I always check the easiest thing to fix first!

Answer (score -2):

In my WP code, I don't include brackets {} around the if statement. My functional code looks like:

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'sidebar1',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '<h2>',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
));
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'sidebar2',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget' => '',
    'before_title' => '<h2>',
    'after_title' => '</h2>',
));
```

Comment: 1) That doesn't answer the question and 2) the second `register_sidebar()` call is now outside the if statement and will be executed regardless of whether the function exists or not. And, IMHO, leaving the brackets out is horrible coding practice, for the reason you just demonstrated.

Comment: @Juhana - thanks for the feedback. After posting this I thought more about it and there's probably something else going on here with this code that's causing the blank screen.